# Prove that the normaliser of a Sylow $2$-subgroups of $D_{2n}$ is itself.

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

> Let $2n = 2^a k$ for $k$ odd. Prove that the normaliser of a Sylow $2$-subgroups of $D_{2n}$ is itself.

Here $|N|\mid |G|$ where $N$ is the normaliser of a sylow $2$ subgroup $H$. But $N$ can properly contain $H$. How to rule out this possibility?

Again I have observed if $a$ is greater than $2$, then $H$ can't contain $r$ to the power $i$ where $i$ is odd.

Comment: I have also tried to show that any g in the group outside H can't take a particular h in H to H but fauled

Answer (score 1):

The statement holds for $k=1$ so we may assume that $k\ne 1$.

We know that $D_{2n}\cong C_{n}\rtimes \langle x\rangle$, where $\langle x\rangle \cong C_{2}\le G$ and acts Frobeniusly on $C_{n}$. Now assume that $p \mid |N_{G}(Q)|$, where $p$ is an odd prime and $Q$ is a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $D_{2n}$. Since any $p$-subgroup of $D_{2n}$ is normal, we get that $PQ=P\rtimes Q$, where $P\ne 1$ is the Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N_{G}(Q)$. Obviously $Q\triangleleft N_{G}(Q)$, so $PQ=P\times Q$. Hence $P\le C_{G}(x)$, a contradiction.

Comment: Glad to see you took this out of the pile of the unanswered questions!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yeah there was no comment or hint so I just solved his problem after 8 years and 11 months! I’m just enjoying my vacation. Just found this website it’s kinda addicting!

Comment: Yes, it is. Watch out. It is possible to get reaaaally addicted. I think one friend has visited the site for over six years (if not more, that particular stat is no longer visible). Every. Single. Day. My longest such a stretch is a bit over a year :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen It’s under control. I’ve been a member for over 3 years, but I’ve been kinda active lately. That was my professor’s suggestion so I enjoy and do not forget subjects while I’m studying new ones. Olympic athletes describe the competitions their most enjoyable part of their careers, and trainings and getting ready for them the hardest part. I can see it in science, it absolutely difficult to self-study but when you get to websites like this it just pays off. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

A visual way of seeing this is to think of a regular $n$-gon and its symmetries (to me this group is called $G=D_n$, but I'm aware that at least Dummit & Foote denote it $D_{2n}$). If $n=2^ak$, $k$ odd, then within a regular $n$-gon we see exactly $k$ regular $2^a$-gons, gotten from each other by rotating the picture by $\pi/n$.

Each of those $2^a$-gons has a copy of $D_{2^a}$ as its group of symmetries. As those symmetries are also symmetries of the $n$-gon, they form a Sylow $2$-subgroup $P$. Because there are exactly $k$ such subgroups, and the number of Sylow $2$-subgroups is equal to $[G:N_G(P)]$, we can conclude that $|N_G(P)|=|G|/k=|P|$. Hence $N_G(P)=P$.

Below please find the example picture of a regular $20$-gon together with the $5$ circumscribed squares. In the action of $D_{20}$ each of the five squares is stabilized by its own copy of a subgroup isomorphic to $D_4$. That's five distinct Sylow $2$-subgroups right there! Hence their normalizers must have order $|D_{20}|/5=8=|D_4|$.
[image]

Comment: I designed this picture originally for [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3721271/11619), but couldn't find it on MSE right away, and had to regenerate it.