# Assume $|G|=40$. Show that the subgroup of order $8$ is normal and unique.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

> Assume a finite group $G$ with $|G| = 40$. Show that the subgroup of
> order $8$ is **normal** and **unique**.

### Attempt:

Since $|G| = 2^3 \cdot 5$, by the $1$st Sylow theorem, $G$ has at least one Sylow $2$-subgroup of order $8$.

Now, using the $3$rd Sylow theorem, the number $N$ of those Sylow $2$-subgroups is an odd number and divides $40$.

Since $1,2,4,5,8,10,20$ are the only divisors of $40$, smaller than $40$, those Sylow $2$-subgroups can either be $1$ or $5$.

If $N = 1$, it can be easily shown that this unique Sylow $2$-subgroup is normal and we're done.

**My problem lies in the $N = 5$ case**:

Assume that there exists $5$ Sylow $2$-subgroups of order $8$ and let $H,K$ be two of them.

Then, because

$$
|HK| = \frac{|H||K|}{|H \cap K|}
$$

$|H \cap K|$ must have at least $2$ elements. If it didn't, $|HK|$ would have $64$ elements, which is a contradiction.

Therefore $N[H \cap K]$'s order is a multiple of $8$ and a divisor of $40$. That leaves us with $|N[H \cap K]| = 40$ an thus:

$$
H \cap K \trianglelefteq  G
$$

Is there a mistake somewhere? I cannot see why $5$ Sylow $2$-subgroups cannot coexist within $G$.

Comment: That's not true. What about the dihedral group of order 40? What is true (and perhaps this is what the question was really about) is that there is only one Sylow $5$-subgroup.

Comment: The equation $|HK|=|H||K|/|H\cap K|$ is not in general true.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Is it not? We have $h_1k_1=h_2k_2$ if and only if $h_2^{-1}h_1=k_2k_1^{-1}\in H\cap K$, and the formula follows from that. For me $$HK=\{hk\in G\mid h\in H, k\in K\}.$$ The trouble being that in general $HK$ need not be a subgroup. If you define $HK$ as the subgroup generated by $H\cup K$ then I agree.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, I understood $HK$ to mean the subgroup generated by $H$ and $K$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To support the argument in the comment by @the_fox , I am posting a proof.

Consider the dihedral group $D_{40}$ with the generators $r,s$ satisfying $o(r)=20,o(s)=2$ and $srs=r^-$

$D_{40}=\{1,s,sr^i,r^i : 1\le i \le 19\}$

Then consider the elements $x=s,y=r^5$, then $xyx=sr^5s=(srs)^5=(r^-)^5=(r^5)^-=y^-$.

Also $o(x)=2,o(y)=4$   and thus $H=\langle x,y\rangle$ is 8 order subgroup of $G$

Now let  $g=sr$ and $y$ be the same as above. Then $o(g)=2$  and

$gyg=srr^5sr=sr^6sr=(srs)^6r=r^{-6}r=(r^5)^-=y^-$

Thus $K=\langle g,y \rangle$  is again a subgroup of order $8$

Now these are not the same subgroups as $sr^6 \in K$ but $ sr^6 \notin H$ which can be easily checked . Since there are more than one $2$-Sylow  subgroup,  it is not normal.

[image]

The various subgroups of eight elements are the groups of symmetries of the five different squares (shown in different colors) inscribed in a regular 20-gon. The big group permutes the five squares, and the Sylow $2$-subgroups are the stabilizers.

Comment: +1 I took the liberty of adding a picture that hopefully makes it clearer to a casual reader what's going on. If you object, feel free to remove it.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen..That is enlightening !! Thanks for the picture.