# Group of order 40 with 5 subgroups of order 8

Tags: abstract-algebra

Would $Z_{40}$ be an example, or the dihedral group $D_{2n}=D_{40}$ work? And how do we obtain the subgroups of $D_{40}$?

Comment: Cyclic groups have only one subgroup of a given order

Comment: What about $D_{40}$?

Comment: Have you seen that subgroup of $S_5$ that has order $20$ and $5$ subgroups of order $4$?

Comment: Also, I recommend that you take a look at [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). Your question falls a bit short of what is expected. It is a bit difficult to compile an answer that would help you. I can post a 1-line answer, one likely to collect a few upvotes even, but it is uncertain that you would find it helpful. Also, I haven't verified that the question has not been handled already :-(

Comment: [The dihedral group of order $40$ works also](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3721271/11619).

Comment: Initially I had in mind the group $C_2\times(C_5\rtimes C_4)$ with abelian Sylow $2$-subgroups, but it was easy to find a previous thread answering your question also.